# Why page position appears to be in the bottom on render in gatsby and window.scrollTo({top: 0}) not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, window, gatsby, reach-router

Hei fellow programmers!

Right to the issue: one particular page, when coming from the previous step always appears to be at the bottom. I'm using Gatsby, is this some kind of normal behaviour? If I'm choosing to go to the page directly through query - it appears normally, at the very top.

And somehow window.scrollTo({top: 0}) does not help in this case ;-(

```
const Checkout: React.FC = () => {
  const { isTablet, isMobile } = useQuery();
  const { goToPayments } = useRouter();
  const [showStickyButton, setShowStickyButton] = useState(true);

  const handleHideElementOnScroll = () => {
    if (scrollY > 40) {
      setShowStickyButton(true);
    } else if (scrollY < 40) {
      setShowStickyButton(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      window.scrollTo({ top: 0 });
      window.addEventListener('scroll', handleHideElementOnScroll);
    }

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleHideElementOnScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Seo title="NixWhite: Oral Care That Matches Your Needs." />
      {showStickyButton && isMobile && (
        <StickyButtonWrapper display="flex">
          <Button
            background={grey}
            color={greyDark}
            onClick={() => goToPayments()}
          >
            Get My Bundle Now
          </Button>
        </StickyButtonWrapper>
      )}
      <Container>
        {isTablet && (
          <H1 margin="0 0 2rem 0">NixWhite© Personalized Oral Care Bundle</H1>
        )}
        <FlexWrapper flexDirection={isTablet ? 'column' : 'row'}>
          <Box margin={isTablet ? '' : '0 3rem 0 0'}>
            <Carousel imageArray={IMAGES} />
          </Box>
          <AboutProduct />
        </FlexWrapper>
      </Container>
      <GuideToSuccess />
      <ShouldBuy />
      <BeforeAfter />
      <Reviews />
      <BillingBottom />
      <FrequentlyAsked />
    </>
  );
};

Checkout.displayName = 'Checkout';

export default Checkout;
```

Comment: _"coming from the previous step always appears to be at the bottom"_ - this makes sense. You've likely scrolled down the page, and then are rendering a new page without reloading. This keeps the scroll position.

Comment: Can you debug the "does not help in this case"? Why? How's the code behaving?